# Update my AVURLAsset while the video is playing (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, http-live-streaming

i'm playing an encrypted m3u8 file and i need to send a new "mykey" update value after certain time to the player.

```
let headers = ["Authorization": "mykey"]
let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: ["AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey": headers])
let avItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avItem)
```

how could i access to the AVURLAsset from the player later on to update my value?

I don't have find anything under...

```
self.avPlayer.items()[0].asset...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call the replaceCurrentItem(with:) function of AVPlayer, Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1390806-replacecurrentitem)

```
let newAvItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: newAvAsset)
avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: newAvItem)
```

Comment: If i replace the current item, the livestream will cut for a 1sec to get the new item, but and don't want that. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do it, the player needs to stop playing current item, lookup new item and start loading & playing